# Replacing a string with sed just concatenates instead of overwriting it

Tags: string, bash, sed, caffe

I have a line which look like the follwoing:

```
input_param { shape: dim: 50 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 277} }
```

I want to overwrite the 50 with a sed command, e.g with a "1":

```
sed -i -e 's/dim: */dim: 1/' filename.txt
```

However the line looks like this afterwards:

```
input_param { shape: dim: 150 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 277} }
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed  's/dim: [0-9]\+/dim: 1/' file
```

You have used `*` means matching zero or more preceding character. So, It didn't check the digits afterwards. I have used `+` means one or more preceding character.